# pandas groupby NA behavior not consistent with R?

Tags: r, pandas

The pandas documentation says:

"NA groups in GroupBy are automatically excluded. This behavior is consistent with R, for example"

I understand the documentation but not how this is consistent with R? Here's an example using a dataframe x with tidyverse.

```
> x
   c b  a
1 NA 1 NA
2 NA 2 NA
3 NA 3  1
4  3 4  2
> x %>% group_by(c, a) %>% summarise(x = mean(b))
Source: local data frame [3 x 3]
Groups: c [?]

      c     a     x
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     3     2   4.0
2    NA     1   3.0
3    NA    NA   1.5
> x %>% group_by(c) %>% summarise(x = mean(b))
# A tibble: 2 × 2
      c     x
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     3     4
2    NA     2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

R is not tidyverse. When the pandas docs says it's consistent with R, it means Base R. Tidyverse functions by different assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

[`datar`](https://github.com/pwwang/datar) tries to follow the API designs of `tidyrverse`:

```py
>>> from datar.all import f, c, tibble, group_by, summarise, mean, NA
>>> x = tibble(c=[NA,NA,NA,3], b=[1,2,3,4], a=[NA,NA,1,2])
>>> x
     c  b    a
0  NaN  1  NaN
1  NaN  2  NaN
2  NaN  3  1.0
3  3.0  4  2.0
>>> x >> group_by(f.c, f.a) >> summarise(x=mean(f.b))
[2021-06-08 12:55:47][datar][   INFO] `summarise()` has grouped output by ['c'] (override with `_groups
` argument)
     c    a    x
0  3.0  2.0  4.0
1  NaN  1.0  3.0
2  NaN  NaN  1.5
[Groups: ['c'] (n=2)]
>>> x >> group_by(f.c) >> summarise(x=mean(f.b))
     c    x
0  3.0  4.0
1  NaN  2.0
```

I am the author of the package. Feel free to submit issues if you have any questions.